# Add class to element if element ID equals post term

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an element that uses term slug as ID.

```
<div id="<?php echo $current_term; ?>" class="collapse">
```

Now, what I can't wrap my head around is how to check whether the ID is the same as the current post term slug, and if so, add class to that element. Let's say I'm currently reading a post that is tagged with term1. If this is the case, the div with ID "term1" should also have a class "show". The other divs with different IDs should not have this class.

```
<div id="term1" class="collapse show">
<div id="term2" class="collapse">
<div id="term3" class="collapse">
```

Is this doable with PHP, or am I looking at the things the wrong way?

This is my whole loop. It queries posts from a category and separates them according to tags. It also adds class "current" to an element that has the same URL as the current URL. Also, I'm using the Bootstrap collapse plugin to open up and close sections.

```
<?php $current_id = $post->ID; ?>
<?php $args = array(
'orderby' => '',
'order' => 'asc'); ?>
<?php $terms = get_tags( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts( array( 
'category_name' => "category1", 
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'meta1',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tag__in' => $term->term_id )); ?> 
<?php $current_term = $term->slug; ?>        
<?php if($posts) : ?>    
<div class="sidebar-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?php echo $current_term; ?>"><?php echo $term->description; ?></a>
    <div id="<?php echo $current_term; ?>" class="collapse">
        <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); $count++; ?>         
        <?php $current_class = ( $current_id == $post->ID ) ? 'current' : ''; ?>
        <a class="<?php if ( $current_class ) echo $current_class; ?> text-nowrap overflow-hidden post-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $id ); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom-field', true) ?></a>   
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
    </div>            
</div>         
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I've also tried using JQuery to add a class only to parent which contains a child with class "current" which is added via PHP, but it doesn't work.

```
$('.current').parent().addClass('show');
```

Comment: what is the url of your post that contains slug?

Comment: URL follows the structure domain/category/post-name. There's no slug in there

Comment: Did you check the `DOM` if `current` class exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your goal is to add the class `show` to all `<div>` elements that have an ID that is equal to the terms of your current post?

If so, I would recommend to get the terms of the current post (this one you are reading) and checking if your `$current_term` is in the terms of the current post.

Maybe this will help you: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Comment: further to this, something once you have all the post terms for the current post you could do something like `in_array($current_term, $otherTerms) ? 'show' : ''`

Comment: Alright, so that works, and this is what I did:

`<?php $post_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' ); ?>`
`<?php foreach ( $post_terms as $post_term ) { ?>`
`<?php $current_post_term = $post_term->slug; ?> `
`<?php } ?>`

And then where the class is applied: 
`<?php echo ($current_term === $current_post_term) ? 'show' : 'hide' ?>`

I'd appreciate feedback if this can be done in a better way, as I'm quite new to php.

Comment: Nice to hear that! You do not need to put every new line of code between `<?php ... ?>`. An example: https://gist.github.com/Cakasim/6f5d6e90ada40039650183791037954b

Have a look at: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Alright, I appreciate it! Copied over your example, and will try to the code cleaner in the future. Cheers.